# Include array element value in another array element?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to have an array assign its own element value to one of its other elements at the time you declare the array?

Here's a code example:

```
$arr = array ( 0 => '<ul class="'.$arr[1].'">', 1 => 'some_class' );

echo $arr[0]; // <ul class="some_class">
```

I've tried [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) (`&$arr[1]` instead of `$arr[1]` in the above code), but it gives a syntax error.

Comment: the `$arr` on the left side of the assignment won't exist until the right-hand side's been evaluated, and `$arr[1]` in the right-hand side can't exist until the right-hand side completes and gets assigned to the left-hand side. e.g. you're trying to count your chickens before chickens even existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along these lines

```
$arr = array ( '<ul class="%s">', 'some_class' );
```

and when you want to render just call

```
echo call_user_func_array("sprintf", $arr);
```

Comment: Would that work if there were more that those 2 elements in the array?

Comment: as long the number of placeholder in the first parameter equals the number of elements in the array (minus 1 for the pattern itself) you are golden.

Comment: That's a really neat trick. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it does fix my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't access an element of an array before the array has been declared. Just use another variable:

```
$class_name = 'some_class'
$arr = array ( 0 => '<ul class="'.$class_name.'">', 1 => $class_name );

echo $arr[0]; // <ul class="some_class">
```

You could also assign elements individually and refer to them in later assignments:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[1] = 'some_class';
$arr[0] = '<ul class="'.$arr[1].'">';

echo $arr[0]; // <ul class="some_class">
```

Comment: I want to make it so that if `$arr[1]` changes, `$arr[0]` will change as well. I'd also like avoid hard-coding `">` at the end of something like `echo $arr[0].$arr[1].'">'` or creating another array element for `">`,  but those appear to be my only choices.

Comment: sounds like a job for a class with a getter/setter for the value, or a rethink of your design. (maybe you need to use more functions?)